# Grep string and put in csv file Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have gz file that have some data now i want to grep two diffrent pattern and put that data into a csv file .For the same i want to write a shell script how can we do this please help me in this.

Below are the two command with i want to grep the data line by line and then put into a csv file .

Commands :

```
zgrep "Time"  file.txt.gz
zgrep "requests" file.txt.gz
```

Please suggest how could i use these command in shell and get the data in a csv file

This is the output i am getting after doing :

```
zgrep -E 'Time|requests' file.txt.gz

 Time 27-Apr-2016 07:24:15 CDT,
 requests currently being processed, 1 
  Time 27-Apr-2016 07:24:15 CDT,
 requests currently being processed, 2 ,
```

I want the ouput like `Time 27-Apr-2016 07:24:15 CDT | requests currently being processed, 1`

Comment: You mean `zgrep -E 'Time|requests'  file.txt.gz > file.csv`?

Comment: Is file.txt.gz a single file or you need to recursively grep inside that directory?

Comment: yes this is single file

Comment: @anubhava this is working but i want both the output as  pipe seprated like TimeOutput | RequestOut\

Comment: I suggest you show your expected output as there can be multiple matches of each word in the file.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: @anubhava i have updated the question please see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` with `gzat`:

```
gzcat file.txt.gz | awk '/Time/{p=$0} /requests/{print p, "|", $0}'
```

Comment: Hmm in that case you will need to gunzip the file first using `gunzip`

Comment: is it `gzat` or `gzcat`?

Comment: @J.Chomel: `gcat` is gnu utility but on OSX we get `gzcat`

Answer (score 1):

Use awk to format it output from grep:

```
zgrep -E ... | awk 'NR%2==0{print l, "|", $0}{l=$0}'
 Time 27-Apr-2016 07:24:15 CDT, |  requests currently being processed, 1 
  Time 27-Apr-2016 07:24:15 CDT, |  requests currently being processed, 2 ,
```

Comment: where is the file name ??

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that 'Time ...' and ;requests ...' in grep output are on one line (not wrapped as in your example).

`zgrep -E 'Time|requests' file.txt.gz | sed -r -e 's/\s*,\s*/ | /' > file.csv`

To remove trailing comma as in `'being processed, 2 ,'` use this variant

`zgrep -E 'Time|requests' file.txt.gz | sed -r -e 's/\s*,\s*/ | /; s/\s*,\s*$//'`

Alternative (pure sed without grep):

`gzip -dc file.txt.gz | sed -r -e '/Time|requests/!d; s/\s*,\s*/ | /; s/\s*,\s*$//'`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `paste` to do so:

```
zgrep -E 'Time'     file.txt.gz >f1
zgrep -E 'requests' file.txt.gz >f2

paste f1 f2
```